# Version control with Visual Studio, should individual project have their own version control?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I currently have a solution wide version control. Is it best practice, or is it better to have version control on each project in the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone probably has their own way of going about it. Personally I would keep the version control solution wide, unless an individual project is able to stand on its own without the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Having different versions for each project is more effort and you should do that only if you need it. E.g. these projects are used by different solutions and may be released in different versions that you have to support independently.

If all that does not apply, stick with one version for all projects.